# The ‘logic’ tag is problematically overused

Tags: discussion, tags

Really excellent question from 12 years ago on this topic: [More specific tags needed to cover questions in logic](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/more-specific-tags-needed-to-cover-questions-in-logic)

I have been regularly going through the highest scoring questions of all time under the ‘logic’ tag and editing and retagging them. Towards the idea of Stack Exchange becoming a compendium of knowledge, I can only dream of a day where one can browse questions, by tags which are as organized as books are under a library subject classification system.

Not only is logic the most used tag on Philosophy SE, but I have also noticed that I am so far unable to keep up with how frequently people post new questions using that tag.

Luckily, I don’t have to repeat the excellent explanation already given by the linked post: “logic” is being used in such a broad way, as a tag here, as is evident given a look at the posts that are using it, that it is almost trivially universal in scope. Anything that has to do with “reasoning” in one way or another (arguably all philosophical questions and questions on SE) is liable to be tagged with “logic”.

So, previously, I thought we should create more specific logic sub-tags. But I am now considering that “logic” should go the way of the “philosophy” tag: our site is now rich enough with diverse content, and active enough, that “logic” is not only no longer sufficient, but it is also no longer necessary. The “philosophy” tag was banned because it offered the perverse incentive of seeming relevant to post content, yet providing virtually no organizational benefit to the site. I believe “logic”’s time has come, as a tag, and that we should consider banning it as simply too broad.

Comment: I agree with your observation. And I think it brings back the question (albeit already discussed here and there) of what kind of logic is accepted here. I find that accepting (often not well formulated) mathematical logic questions just makes the philosophy SE look like an approximative and informal math SE.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a [large set of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/1822475/philosophy-questions-tagged-only-as-logic) are *only* tagged with [logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic). We should consider whether we want to do anything about that (I would suggest retagging as [formal-logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-logic) or [symbolic-logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-logic), perhaps), or if we just leave them as-is and allow the tag to remain. To my understanding, the system will not mass-remove a blocked tag from existing questions - it will simply prevent those questions from being edited (unless the edit removes the blocked tag).